# Using ffplay to preview a USB webcam using DirectShow under Windows 10 gives black screen

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, directshow

When using ffplay to preview a USB webcam using DirectShow filter under Windows 10 Pro gives black screen.

Tried CamDiag32 and CamDiag64, both shows quartz.dll missing but it pop an "access denied error" when I right click and choose fix. CamDiag64 can still preview the webcam but CamDiag32 gives black screen. I have tried regsvr32 under command prompt with Admin privileges for both quartz in System32 and SysWOW64 it seems successfully registered but CamDiagXX still complains about the quartz.dll issues.

Also tried GraphEdit by pinning the capture pin to video render also gives black screen.

Not sure the root cause of the problem.

```
C:\Temp>ffplay.exe -f dshow -i "video=Vimicro USB Camera (Altair)"
ffplay version N-94129-g098ab93257 Copyright (c) 2003-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190621
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 29.100 / 56. 29.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.100 / 58. 53.100
  libavformat    58. 28.101 / 58. 28.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Vimicro USB Camera (Altair)':B f=0/0
  Duration: N/A, start: 2664.043000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc
2734.21 M-V:  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

```
C:\Temp>ffplay.exe -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
ffmpeg version N-94129-g098ab93257 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190621
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 29.100 / 56. 29.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.100 / 58. 53.100
  libavformat    58. 28.101 / 58. 28.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
[dshow @ 0000022188bb8a00] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 0000022188bb8a00]  "Vimicro USB Camera (Altair)"
[dshow @ 0000022188bb8a00]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_0ac8&pid_3450&mi_00#6&22d596c2&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

```
C:\Temp>ffplay.exe -f dshow -i "video=Vimicro USB Camera (Altair)" -list_options true
ffplay version N-94129-g098ab93257 Copyright (c) 2003-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190621
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 29.100 / 56. 29.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.100 / 58. 53.100
  libavformat    58. 28.101 / 58. 28.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
[dshow @ 000001b0b698ca40] DirectShow video device options (from video devices)
[dshow @ 000001b0b698ca40]  Pin "Capture" (alternative pin name "0")
[dshow @ 000001b0b698ca40]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x480 fps=30 max s=640x480 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001b0b698ca40]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x480 fps=30 max s=640x480 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001b0b698ca40]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=352x288 fps=30 max s=352x288 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001b0b698ca40]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=352x288 fps=30 max s=352x288 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001b0b698ca40]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=320x240 fps=30 max s=320x240 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001b0b698ca40]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=320x240 fps=30 max s=320x240 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001b0b698ca40]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=176x144 fps=30 max s=176x144 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001b0b698ca40]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=176x144 fps=30 max s=176x144 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001b0b698ca40]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=160x120 fps=30 max s=160x120 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001b0b698ca40]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=160x120 fps=30 max s=160x120 fps=30
video=Vimicro USB Camera (Altair): Immediate exit requested f=0/0
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error, here's the correction

ffplay.exe -f dshow -i video=**"**Vimicro USB Camera (Altair)**"**

Comment: What was the difference?  It works for me with quotes either after video= or before?